# Postgres equivalent of ANY ... SATISFIES in n1ql to combine ANY and IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql++

I know in n1ql, you can write a query condition that combines `ANY` and `IN` operators like so:

```
WHERE ANY v IN [v1, v2] SATISFIES v IN c1 END
```

I'm trying to rewrite the same query in postgres, and right now I'm using `OR` like so:

```
WHERE v1 IN c1
OR v2 IN c1
```

But is there an equivalent to `SATISFIES` that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `c1` is a subquery, you could use the array overlap operator `&&`:

```
WHERE ARRAY[v1, v2] && array(SELECT ...)
```

That will be `TRUE` if the arrays have elements in common, which should do what you want.

Comment: sorry i should've been more clear, c1 is a column. for example, my query condition looks something like:
```WHERE col->path->to->json->>field IN (SELECT col1 from table1)
OR col->path->to->another->>field IN (SELECT col1 from table1)```
where col contains a json object

Comment: It also works with a subquery, see my adapted answer.

Comment: that works, thanks! it looks like it might be saving me some milliseconds as well. do you know if this is more efficient because it doesn't perform the `SELECT ...` twice (once for each side of the `OR`)?

Comment: That will certainly be an advantage, yes. If the subquery is expensive, it will make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking along the lines of an array, something like this...

```
    select *
    from my_table
    where array[v1, v2] @> array[c1]
```

db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qfJzyF6sfoNfFxRKtXa1W/0